# Can't Use Maven Environment Variables in Jenkins CI

Tags: maven, jenkins, environment-variables

So I'm trying use a Python script to get some information out of Jenkins after it's done with a Maven build, but the Maven environment variables that are supposed to be set (see [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+maven2+project)) are not. Anyone know whats up? I'm using the latest version of Jenkins.

Comment: Dangit I just realized that the Maven plugin that has that functionality is not released yet.

Comment: How about adding it as an answer and marking it as a correct one? To follow the process here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the version that supports environment variables isn't out yet.